# How to avoid double construction of proxy with DynamicProxy::CreateClassProxyWithTarget?

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

I am decorating an existing object using the `CreateClassProxyWithTarget` method. However, the constructor and therefore, initialization code, is being called twice. I already have a "constructed" instance (the target). I understand why this happens, but is there a way to avoid it, other than using an empty constructor?

Edit: Here is some code:

First the proxy creation:

```
public static T Create<T>(T i_pEntity) where T : class
{
  object pResult = m_pGenerator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(typeof(T),
                                                           new[] 
                                                             { 
                                                                typeof(IEditableObject),
                                                                typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged) ,
                                                                typeof(IMarkerInterface),
                                                                typeof(IDataErrorInfo)
                                                             },                                                               
                                                           i_pEntity,
                                                           ProxyGenerationOptions.Default,
                                                           new BindingEntityInterceptor<T>(i_pEntity));
  return (T)pResult;
}
```

I use this for example with an object of the following class:

```
public class KatalogBase : AuditableBaseEntity
{
   public KatalogBase()
   {
     Values     = new HashedSet<Values>();
     Attributes = new HashedSet<Attributes>();
   }
   ...
}
```

If i now call `BindingFactory.Create(someKatalogBaseObject);` the `Values` and `Attributes`
properties are beeing initialized again.

Comment: Can you elaborate with some code that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic I have updated my question with some code, that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based off [one of Krzysztof's articles](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors.aspx) and his [comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/moqdisc/TLzsNyg86kk) on the Moq forum, I have managed to get this working:

```
 class MyProxyGenerator : ProxyGenerator
    {
        public object CreateClassProxyWithoutRunningCtor(Type type, ProxyGenerationOptions pgo, SourcererInterceptor sourcererInterceptor)
        {
            var prxType = this.CreateClassProxyType(type, new Type[] { }, pgo);
            var instance = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(prxType);
            SetInterceptors(instance, new IInterceptor[]{sourcererInterceptor});
            return instance;
        }


        private void SetInterceptors(object proxy, params IInterceptor[] interceptors)
        {
            var field = proxy.GetType().GetField("__interceptors");
            field.SetValue(proxy, interceptors);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you're asking is if DynamicProxy can construct the proxy instance without calling its constructor?

That is not really possible. There is a way using `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()` but doesn't work in medium trust.

Comment: No thats not exactly what i'm asking :-) As i said it is clear that the constructor has to be called.  But if i already have a target my understanding is, that every call is forwarded to the target or handled by the interceptor. This makes no sense, if the proxy overrides the target object during construction. The proxy object can call the constructor and initialize the Values and Attributes properties (see example above). But if I call proxy.Values i thought it will simply forwarded to target.Values. In this case it doesn't matter, that the proxy has initialized the properties for itself.